# Copy favorite songs and artists from Pandora to Last.fm?

Tags: music, pandora, last.fm

Is there a automagical way that I can copy my favorites from Pandora to Last.FM?

Answer (score 1):

Good news :)
This may be what you are looking for! http://build.last.fm/item/270 via: http://www.last.fm/group/Connect+Last.fm